# Vercel: RollupError: Could not resolve "./pages/Auth/Auth.jsx" from "src/App.jsx"

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

I am trying to deploy my vite-react app to vercel but it keeps throwing the following error:
[Vercel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Mcx.png)

The code Works Perfectly locally on my PC both in dev and prod
Directory Structure:

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlHzi.png)

Imports in App.jsx:

```
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    import Auth from "./pages/Auth/Auth.jsx";
    import "./assets/normalize.css";
    import Code from "./pages/Code/Code.jsx";
    import "./config.css"
    import Profile from "./pages/Profile/Profile.jsx";
```

I checked for case sensitivity, stuctures and even removing unused libraries.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).